# How can I create puzzle pieces from an image and reveal the full image on a button click in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two views stacked on top of each other. The first view is called "containerView" and contains information about a person. The second view is called "profileImageView" and displays the person's image.

Initially, only containerView is visible. However, when the user clicks on the "Reveal Face" button, profileImageView is displayed and containerView is hidden. I want to display the profileImageView with a puzzle effect, gradually revealing the entire image.

I want to gradually reveal an image by starting with random puzzle pieces.

```
var puzzlePieces = [UIView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpPuzzleView()
    }

func setUpPuzzleView() {
        self.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "photo")

// Break the face image into puzzle pieces and scatter them randomly
        for row in 0..<4 {
            for column in 0..<4 {
                let pieceWidth = self.profileImageView.bounds.width / 4
                let pieceHeight = self.profileImageView.bounds.height / 4
                
                let pieceFrame = CGRect(
                    x: CGFloat(column) * pieceWidth,
                    y: CGFloat(row) * pieceHeight,
                    width: pieceWidth,
                    height: pieceHeight
                )
                
                let puzzlePiece = UIView(frame: pieceFrame)
                puzzlePiece.layer.contents = cropImage(image: self.profileImageView.image!, rect: pieceFrame).cgImage
                puzzlePiece.isHidden = true
                profileImageView.addSubview(puzzlePiece)
                puzzlePieces.append(puzzlePiece)
                
                // Randomly scatter puzzle pieces
                let randomXOffset = CGFloat.random(in: -100...100)
                let randomYOffset = CGFloat.random(in: -100...100)
                puzzlePiece.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: randomXOffset, y: randomYOffset)
    }

// MARK: - Crop Image
func cropImage(image: UIImage, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let scale = image.scale
        let croppedRect = CGRect(
            x: rect.origin.x * scale,
            y: rect.origin.y * scale,
            width: rect.size.width * scale,
            height: rect.size.height * scale
        )
        
        if let croppedCGImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: croppedRect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage, scale: scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        }
        return UIImage()
    }

// MARK: - IBActions
@IBAction func onRevealPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.containerView.isHidden = true
            self.profileImageView.isHidden = false
            for puzzlePiece in self.puzzlePieces {
                puzzlePiece.transform = .identity
                puzzlePiece.isHidden = false // Reveal puzzle pieces
            }
        }
    }
```

I have successfully created puzzle pieces. see image link: https://ibb.co/F7LfKwB

The issue I'm facing is after clicking on button, a whole new view is created on my profileImageView with some top-right corner radius. see image link: https://ibb.co/J7YrhFN

Any Kind of help would be highly appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: When you have all the puzzle pieces created, can you take a screenshot of the debug view hierarchy? my guess is that the frames when cropping the image is slightly off so there's an offset happening, https://medium.com/stacc/utilizing-the-debug-view-hierarchy-to-better-understand-your-apps-ui-c8655f6d34e9

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have attached images here: https://ibb.co/pbVykmG
and https://ibb.co/BNRdkNG
I guess my cropping function is causing issues as I'm just a beginner I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

Comment: Yeah definitely something funky going on with the frame calculations when cropping! I'd recommend placing debug breakpoints in your crop function and making sure the calculations make sense (recommend just printing out all the different values that are being used). https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711

Comment: Yes, I have printed out all the values, I guess I'm not able to understand the frame calculations when cropping! I have tried debugging by placing breakpoints. Thanks for your suggestions :)